# Quarto Reveal slides: text color for a single slide

Tags: r, reveal.js, quarto

Below I paste a Quarto document which produces a reveal.js slide deck with 2 slides, using the default theme.

How do I change the color of the header and of the main text **on a single slide**, while keeping all other slides at the default theme? If possible, I would like the syntax to be relatively concise.

```
---
format: revealjs
---

## Slide 1: Black header (default)

Black text (default)

## Slide 2: Red header

Red text
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option can be targeting that specific slide using id and then apply CSS rule for that id.

````
---
title: "Text Color for single Slide"
format: revealjs
engine: knitr
---


## Slide 1: Black header (default)

Black text (default)

## Slide 2: Red header{#color-slide}

```{css, echo=FALSE}
#color-slide, 
#color-slide h2 {
 color: red;
}

```

Red Text

## Slide 3: Black header (default)

Black text (default)
````

---

[image: overview of slides - css applied using id]

---

And using CSS class, instead of id, would be useful if we want to apply those same CSS rules on more than one slide.

````
---
title: "Text Color for single Slide"
format: revealjs
engine: knitr
---


## Slide 1: Black header (default)

Black text (default)

## Slide 2: Red header{.color-slide}

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.color-slide, 
.color-slide h2 {
 color: red;
}

```

Red Text

## Slide 3: Black header (default)

Black text (default)


## Slide 4: Red header{.color-slide}

Red Text
````

---

[image: overview of slides - css applied using class]

---

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I think I'll need to use a CSS class as you suggested at the end. However, I can't get the class to apply to headers. Would you have an example? No problem if you don't, of course...

Comment: @Vincent, updated my answer with the case of using class. It's pretty much the same thing. Wondering why it didn't work in your case.

Comment: No idea what I missed. This works great!